# The menu appears on mobile and then disappears

Tags: wordpress, menu

When my menu opens on mobile, the first texts appear, then after 5 seconds it returns to normal. You will understand when you see it on mobile, I am adding a photo. I would be glad if you help.

dentdenizli.com.tr

https://prnt.sc/JkIHTl40FsNb

Hello,
When my menu opens on mobile, the first texts appear, then after 5 seconds it returns to normal. You will understand when you see it on mobile, I am adding a photo. I would be glad if you help.

Comment: The problem is that its adding class .mobile-menu while loading or resizing your screen. You need to add media screen rule early as possible to hide it.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like issue with internet speed. The CSS is taking a while to load and hence its gets normal in few seconds. Can you try opening the page from mobile with good internet connectivity.

Also ensure you have the CSS file links as the first in the head. If this still does not solves the issue, put the content of CSS inside a style tag in HTML Head tag.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. Our internet speed is good, we have tried it from different places and it is the same. On mobile, the menu appears and then disappears again.